Как получить информацию об игре в Steam без использования python-steam-api?
Как я могу получить название, описание, цену игры, но не использовать "python-steam-api"?
В документации Valve указаны только возможности получения информации о пользователе, и только через них можно получать какую-либо информацию об игре, но опять же она будет лишь поверхностная
Рассматривал эту документацию - https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Я хочу получить информации о игре с использованием steam api, но при этом не использовать  "python-steam-api"

Ты можешь получать эту информацию через парсер сайтов. Рекомендую посмотреть на bs4 и использовать библиотеку request или aioreqest.
